# Join 4 tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Tables that I want to join :

```
    order:
    order_id | id_user | movie_title | date | time |

    seat_order:
    seat_order_id | order_id | id_seat |

    seat:
    seat_id | row | number | status |

    user:
    user_id | username | email | password |
```

and I want the result after join like this:

```
| email | movie_title | date | time | seat | status |
```

I can join three tables using this query, but when I try to join with `user` table it always shows an error.

```
SELECT order.movie_title,date,time,user_id,
       seat_order.seat_id,
       seat.row,number,status
FROM order
JOIN seat_order
ON order.order_id=seat_order.order_id
JOIN seat
ON seat_order.seat_id=seat.seat_id
WHERE seat.status='reserved'
```

I need your help to join with the `user` table without error.

Comment: write the error or you want us all to test your code...

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word, so not the best choice for a table name

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could Update your question with Create Table structure and also supply some script to prepare raw data, so it would be ready available with you,

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't use order name.. i use just in here.. to make reader easy to understand my question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest join you can do is:

```
SELECT user.email, order.movie_title, order.date, order.time, seat.row, seat.number, seat.status
FROM
user
INNER JOIN order ON user.user_id = order.id_user
INNER JOIN seat_order ON order.order_id = seat_order.order_id
INNER JOIN seat ON seat_order.seat_order_id = seat.seat_id
```

Comment: As said by @Strawberry, since order is a reserved word you might try to change that table name.
What kind of error do you get?

Comment: i'm sorry my mistake.. to write wrong name.. it works thank you

Comment: In MySQL `inner join` and `join` are the same

Answer (score -1):

Please check below query,

```
SELECT 
user.email, 
order.movie_title, 
order.date, 
order.time, 
seat.row, 
seat.number, 
seat.status 
FROM 
user 
INNER JOIN order on order.id_user = user.user_id 
INNER JOIN seat_order on seat_order.order_id = order.order_id 
INNER JOIN seat on seat.seat_id = seat_order.id_seat;
```

Comment: Join on? How's that helpful?